# Image not showing up with other hashtagged images and Gramblr

Tags: block, instagram, hashtag

I am not a developer but I am a university researcher studying informal education through social media.

Recently I just had my account disabled when I tested the application gramblr for uploading photos to Instagram. As I have a few members of my learning community who wanted to participate but could not afford a smartphone I wanted to find them alternate options.

Presently anything I upload and tag does not show up amidst other images with the same tag.

This is a big problem as I am the lead researcher and the community organizer, and I lead through example, as well as create various educational avenues through the use of tags.

Please help me to resolve this issue as soon as is possible.

Thank you
-Lily

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Gramblr actually broke my Instagram account. I had to delete it and start with a new account. Here is how I figured out how to upload photos from my PC with no smart phone:

1 - Download and install BlueStacks: http://www.bluestacks.com/ When running, this program will produce an environment in which you can run popular apps on your computer.

2 - Search for the Instagram app within the BlueStacks App Player & install it. Also search for the Roots Browser app and install it as well (you'll use this app to upload photos from your computer.)

3 - Open Instagram inside BlueStacks & either register a new account or sign in with an existing one.

4 - Open the Roots Browser app and navigate to the desired folder where you will be storing images copied from your computer. I chose SD Card > Pictures. Pull the image(s) into the folder & drop it. It will ask you where you want to send it - choose Instagram.

5 - Open the Instagram app. To upload photos from your computer you must go into the Instagram settings (maybe under Advanced Settings) and disable/uncheck the Instagram camera. In the lastest updates the placement of this checkbox option has changed, so it may take some looking around to find it.

6 - In the Instagram app, click on the camera icon to upload a photo. Choose gallery & then navigate through your Root Browser to the folder where you dragged in your chosen image(s). Choose an image.

7 - Post as you would normally by following the prompts/icons to progress.

I ran into 1 more issue. It turns out that my BlueStacks Instagram app would get stuck after choosing the photo & trying to continue with posting. The screen would turn black & nothing happened for a very long time. I ended up having to update my graphics card drivers & that fixed the problem. If you need help updating your graphics card driver(s) see the http://www.ma-config.com/en website. It will help you to figure out what drivers can be updated. You'll have to download the proper version for your computer operating system & install it on your computer. Double click the icon on your desktop after installation to run it & then hit the refresh button in the browser on the ma-config website. Follow prompts to download drivers needed.

This is the method that worked for me. There are several other methods if you search YouTube with combinations of words including BlueStack & Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

Blue stacks has tons of adware/malware etc. according to my security software, the better work around is dropbox. Put the image in drop box on your computer, then on your phone select your photo from dropbox. A bit long winded but it works.